# remove special characters in starting in a column python Data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Have a column called company_permalink in csv file(company).After i loaded into python,how can i print only company names from the below column?

```
/organization/-fame
/ORGANIZATION/-QOUNTER
/organization/-qounter
/ORGANIZATION/-THE-ONE-OF-THEM-INC-
/organization/0-6-com
/ORGANIZATION/004-TECHNOLOGIES
/organization/01games-technology
/ORGANIZATION/0NDINE-BIOMEDICAL-INC
/organization/0ndine-biomedical-inc
/ORGANIZATION/0XDATA
/organization/0xdata
/ORGANIZATION/0XDATA
/organization/0xdata
/ORGANIZATION/1
/organization/1
/ORGANIZATION/1
/organization/1-2-3-listo
/ORGANIZATION/1-4-ALL
/organization/1-618-technology
/ORGANIZATION/1-800-DENTIST

import re
import string
b = company['company_permalink'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[2])
b.map(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', x))
```

Need to extract company names

Comment: Please indicate your expected output so people are clear on what you want before throwing answers at you.

Comment: I have a data set  like below.need to extract company names :     /Organization/-Fame #fame http://livfame.com Media operating IND 16 Mumbai Mumbai 
/Organization/-Qounter :Qounter http://www.qounter.com Application Platforms|Real Time|Social Network Media operating USA DE DE - Other Delaware City 04-09-2014

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I know you want to extract something, I'm asking what the expected output _is_. Please [edit] your question with the desired output for the data given.

Comment: Out put should be like this:   fame
Qounter 
The-One-Of-Them-Inc
0-6-Com
004-Technologies
01Games-Technology
0Ndine-Biomedical-Inc
0Xdata 
1 One Inc.
Qounter 
The-One-Of-Them-Inc
0-6-Com 
004-Technologies
01Games-Technology
0Ndine-Biomedical-Inc 
0Xdata H2O.ai 
1 
1-2-3-Listo
1-4-All 
1-618-Technology
1-800-Dentist
1-800-Doctors 
1-800-Publicrelations-Inc
1-Mainstream
1-Of-99

Comment: Do you need something like `df['company_permalink'].str.rsplit('/', 1).str[-1].str.replace(r'(?i)^\W*|[^a-z]$', '').unique()`?

Comment: Yes.but got the below error

Comment: Yes.but got the below error: Yes.but got the below output: array(['Fame', 'Qounter', 'The-One-Of-Them-Inc', ..., 'Ã\x81Eron',
       'Ã\x94Asys-', 'Ä°Novatiff-Reklam-Ve-Tanä±Tä±M-Hizmetleri-Tic'],
      dtype=object)   Not correct output

Comment: Yeah and what's the problem with it? Are you looking to add the result as a new column instead? Your "expected output" in your previous comments did not indicate as such.

Comment: If you are talking about the weird symbols, that means your data has been incorrectly decoded. I don't know your encoding but that's not something I can help with, without further context.

Comment: Have executed: companies['permalink'].str.rsplit('/', 1).str[-1].str.replace(r'(?i)^\W*|[^a-z]$', '')        But could see ascii chars like :   ÃEron
  ÃAsys-
  Ä°Novatiff-Reklam-Ve-Tanä±Tä±M-Hizmetleri-Tic